# Swap column values in Spark Dataframe where one is string and other is string inside a struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in dataframe as follows

```
{"A", {4,"B"}}
```

Schema :

```
{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"lastname","nullable":false,"type":"string","metadata":{}},{"name":"name","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"mid","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"firstname","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}
```

I want to swap values "A" and "B" so that the output looks like below

```
{"B", {4,"A"}}
```

Can we achieve this without using functions like map? Can withColumn, select be used to achieve this in Java? I want to avoid using any row level action like map because we need to pass Encoders to those functions and due to some limitation I cannot pass encoder.

df.show()

```
+--------+------+
|lastname|  name|
+--------+------+
|       A|[4, B]|
|       C|[5, D]|
+--------+------+
```

df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = false)
 |-- name: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mid: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you show the output for `df.show()` and `df.printSchema` for better undertanding ?

Comment: @Sanket9394  Added to the question

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `select` and `struct` as below

```
df.select($"name.firstName".as("lastName"),
  struct("name.mid", "lastName").as("name")
).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+
|lastName|name  |
+--------+------+
|B       |{4, A}|
|D       |{5, C}|
+--------+------+
```